# Config eclipse preferences in project explorer

Tags: eclipse

Can I config somewhere which options there are when I make a right click in the project explorer and there is the extended menu of "new" and change for example "new php project" to "new php file"? Thanks for yout answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the top level of the 'File > New' menu using 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' dialog (or just 'Window > Customize Perspective' before Eclipse Mars).

Choose the 'Shortcuts' tab and configure the items you want to appear.

Answer (score 0):

The items that are available in that submenu is based on the context, on whatever you have selected when you right-click. For example, if you right-click on an existing PHP project, *then* you should see an option to create a new PHP file *in that project*.

Keep in mind that Eclipse is fundamentally project-based; you can't really create files outside of a project.